# What is "Out-of-band Remote Access"?

Tags: computer-architecture, hardware-detection, intel-core2

DMIDECODE:

```
Handle 0x001E, DMI type 30, 6 bytes
Out-of-band Remote Access
  Manufacturer Name: Intel
  Inbound Connection: Disabled
  Outbound Connection: Enabled
```

LSHW:

```
*-remoteaccess UNCLAIMED
       vendor: Intel
       physical id: 2
       capabilities: outbound
```

LSHW GUI:
[Image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0JajL.png)

Answer (score 1):

#### What is “Out-of-band Remote Access”?

This allows remote monitoring of networks.

> **Out-of-Band**
>
> Out-of-Band Network Access Control appliances watch traffic from
>   outside of the network. They make a copy of any traffic that goes
>   through, and they review it. They report on the harmful things that
>   have come through, and make changes so that they can’t happen again.
>   By copying every piece of traffic, and then sending code through for
>   remediation, they essentially double the amount of traffic coming
>   through, slowing down your network. Out-of-Band NACs also have to be
>   compatible with your specific network equipment.
>
> Out-of-band Network Access Control solutions offer some of the policy
>   smarts for NAC but leave the enforcement elements to Ethernet
>   switches, VPN concentrators and wireless access points. They also
>   require endpoint agents, which can be removed from the devices,
>   especially if they are personal or BYOD devices.
>
> These solutions rely on Layer-3 ACLs and Layer-2 VLANs for some
>   traffic segmentation, but offer no enforcement, and are extremely weak
>   at identity-based access control, the cornerstone of NAC.
>
> These solutions are also very dependent on the types of switches,
>   access points and VPN concentrators, and on the software versions
>   running on these devices.
>
> They have so many moving parts and management issues as to make their
>   deployment, beyond an interesting lab demonstration, a costly
>   proposition.
>
> **Inline**
>
> Inline Network Access Controls, sit right on your network. They’re
>   able to stop threats as they emerge, instead of having to remediate
>   them later. It's a common misconception that having an inline NAC will
>   slow down your network. The reality is that while it looks at every
>   piece of data coming through, it only needs to do it once. As you can
>   see above, Out-of-Band not only makes copies, doubling the traffic,
>   but it sends through more traffic when making repairs.
>
> Inline doesn’t need to talk with the switches, routers, or other
>   networking equipment, and is therefore agnostic. It can be used with
>   any type of network.
>
> Inline solutions offer the most effective NAC functionality, including
>   traffic inspection, and when deployed in a standard network require
>   almost no changes to existing network equipment.
>
> These solutions offer a complete NAC lifecycle without the integration
>   costs, moving parts, switch upgrades to the latest and greatest
>   software patches, and changes in configuration required on the
>   network.

Source [Inline vs. Out-of-Band :: MiltonSecurity.com](https://www.miltonsecurity.com/support/faqs/inline)